# How indicate when a functions was upgraded in relationship to the entire program

Tags: comments, documentation

for inline documentation there are those @somethings for some php documenter, when

there is the common @since @version and so on.

I have a lot of functions that are all part of a big package. But what if i want to indicate when i last updated a function and show on what version of the mayor package it was done?

should i just use @version and give the function the version of the entire package?

In case i cause confusion:

lets say i have a function with @since 0.1 in my program 1.0. then the program itself gets developed up to 2.9 and for the 3.0 version the function would have a change.

So actually the functions version would be 0.2 now but i want to show on what version of my entire programm it was updated. So should i just jump and say @version 3.0 at this function?

i just used a @updated but thats not existing right? [nothing like this documented here](http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.since.pkg.html)

Is there anything for my purpose?

Comment: The question is not about WordPress, it’s about software development in a wider scope. I wanted to move to programmers but they don’t want it.

Comment: Yeah i know, i can't post in SO anymore so i did this here. Could have been migrated, but why bother just close thanks for nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Inline docs are the place to track changes. There are better tools for that: [revision control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control). Use Git, Mercurial or – if you want to stay old-school ;) – SVN.

Each time you change something, you make a *commit:* A short note explaining the difference between the last and the new version ([example](https://github.com/toscho/Public-Contact-Data/commit/5c770e1812b87f24a1ffc161cfe457f2c504cd93)).

Usually, when you look at source code you want to know what it does *right now*. And why. These docs are important. Everything else, including `@since`, doesn’t really belong to comments.

Comment: I use Git. And this is not answering the question its just a lecture you gave because you expect me to be stupid, i want to see exactly that in my source even if i use git. So i will just use @updated even if it not exists. It's for humans, i just wanted to know it there it something for this purpose then i would have done is for humans and robots at the same time and no lecture about what YOU would do.